# Lodash _.some is not working

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash to find if a `key` exists in an array of objects, but it doesn't seem to find them even though they are there:

```
var dtRng = ["1420070400000","1422748800000","1425168000000", etc];

var scnFtprntDates = { "values": [
    { "key": "1420070400000", "values": 289819.9054 },
    { "key": "1422748800000", "values": 289819.9054 },
    { "key": "1425168000000", "values": 289819.9054 },
    etc
]};

var scn2 = scnFtprntDates.values
var lngth = scn2.length

for (var q = 0; q < dtRng.length; q++) {
    if (_.some([scn2], ["key", dtRng[q]])) {
        console.log("found");
    } else {
        console.log("not found"); 
    }
}
```

seems to return all `not found` in the console log...

Comment: To help everyone understand your question, please use meaningful names and if possible and make the example minimal. I don't think it's necessary to have 60 strings and objects for the sake of the question.

Comment: Please, do not correct the code of your question based on the answers received as it makes them irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wrapping your collection in an extra array, remove the square brackets

```
if (_.some(scn2, ["key", dtRng[q]])) { 
  ....
```

Comment: doesn't it wrap it in brackets though? trying to follow this doc...https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#some

Comment: @user2061886 `scn2` is already an array, there's no need to nest it in a new array. In the example, it's primitives: `[null, 0, 'yes', false]` which should be passed within an array.

Comment: Checkout the third example at that link, the first argument should be an array of objects, which`scn2` already is.

Comment: gotcha...just tried to do that but still got the same result...here is a fiddle too of it that I just made...https://jsfiddle.net/6Lmnernf/

Comment: Your fiddle appears to work fine to me - what output are you expecting in the console?

Comment: you're right...it does work...my `dtRng` is not what I expected now which is a different problem...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lodash for that, this simple one-liner does it for you:

```
dtRng.forEach(k => { const result = scnFtprntDates.values.filter(obj => obj.key === k).length > 0 ? 'found' : 'not found'; console.log(k, result) })
```